# How do i handle the exception in an own function that Java compiles again?

Tags: java, exception

As mentionend in the Subject: Java forces me to return something, because the handling of the Exception is in an own function.

```
public String returnLel(String mattDamon) {

  try {
    trick(mattDamon); // The LelException could be thrown
    return "lel";    

  } catch (LelException e) {
    handleException();
  }
}

public void handleException() {
  throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

`

Comment: You have to return something because you designed the method to to so, not because of the exception handling.

Comment: But there is no way that there won't be something returned. If the exception is thrown a runtime-exception is crashing the program

Comment: This won't compile since `handleException` doesn't return anything (or `void`).

Comment: the compiler is not smart enough to know that `handleException` will always throw an exception (which is a good thing, because such "optimization" would only serve to hypothetical cases like yours anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not compile because the compiler is not "clever" enough to know you are throwing a `RuntimeException` in `handleException`.

In order for your code to compile you can either:

- directly `throw new RuntimeException();` in your `catch` statement (ugly)
- `return null` after invoking `handleException();` (acceptable, but still kind of ugly)
- add a `finally` statement to finalize your method and return `null` or whatever **if** some condition has not been met (recommended)

Also note that I'm assuming `LelException extends RuntimeException`, otherwise your `catch` statement won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is up to you on how you will handle the situation.

If you are able to handle the exception by say logging it and just return null as most of the comments imply that is totally o.k.

Just consider that this situation could also mean that the method "returnLel" might not be the correct place to handle this exception but to let the caller decide what to do in this situation by "throwing it further" like so:

```
public String returnLel(String mattDamon) throws LelException{
    trick(mattDamon); // The LelException could be thrown
    return "lel";    
}
```

This means if the caller calls your returnLel-Method he will have to try/catch the Exception (or throw it further up) and could in this case mean a better design because the caller will not receive `null` or a `String' but a`String`or a`LeLException` instead

Answer (score 0):

Move the return statement out of the try catch.

The try block should surround the part where an exception could be thrown, what the return statement not does.

Here the java tutorials for some basic knowledge about this topic:

- [The try Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)
- [The catch Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)
- [The finally Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)